# Checking if a user and a password introduced in a form exist on SQL database

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2015

First post here so, first of all, thanks for the existence of this site since it has helped me lots so far.

Right now I'm making a project (C#) that requires a user to login. The profiles are stored on an SQL base and I need to check if the credentials (user/pass) are correct to allow the login.

I understand very little of SQL, so bare with my errors, please.

The form is working quite nicely. What doesn't work is the data check on my database. So, when I press login the form calls the following function:

public bool ValidacaoLogin(string user, string pass)

```
        cn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from BDPerfil left join BDPerfilTecnico on BDPerfil.USER = BDPerfilTecnico.USER where BDPerfil.USER = @USER;", cn);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from BDPerfil where NIF = '" + user + "' AND PASSWORD = '" + pass + "';", cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USER", user);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", pass);
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if ("@USER" == user)
                {
                    if ("@PASSWORD" == pass)
                        dr.Close();
                    cn.Close();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
            return false;
    }
```

I have 2 tables to store different profiles: BDPerfilTecnico and BDPerfilAssist so I want my program to check both (through join) although right now I don't need to use BDPerfilAssist since all my test profiles are on BDPerfilTecnico.

Help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Checking for a password this way, means that it is stored as clear-text. Usually this is frowned upon (to put it mildly)

Comment: You get only the rows back that have the supplied username and password. So no row = unknown combination; any rows = success. No need to check the row again (with a failing `if ("@USER" == user)` etc).

Comment: @Hans Kesting
"Checking for a password this way, means that it is stored as clear-text. Usually this is frowned upon (to put it mildly)"

I know. But this is for class and we haven't been taught on how to encrypt data, so... It will suffice.

I didn't quite get what you said after, though. It means that I don't need to do the boolean for "@USER" == user and "@PASSWORD" == pass?

Comment: When you get rows back, you already know the username and password matched. So you don't need to check again. And "failing" because that "@USER" or "@PASSWORD" in your ifs are just plain strings where I guess it was meant to be either the parameter value or the column value. This might be why it is "still failing to accept credentials".

Comment: As for the password in clear text: for a class assignment that is OK, as long as you know that "in real life" it has to be hashed.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you need the parameters in the query.  I would expectd:

```
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from BDPerfil where NIF = @USER AND PASSWORD = @PASSWORD'", cn);
```

You are onto a good path using parameters for the queries.  You just need them in the query itself.

Note:  There may be other issues in the code as well.

Comment: "Note: There may be other issues in the code as well."

I bet there are. First time working with SQL. Don't know much about it so I'm prone to do lots of mistakes as is.
But thanks for the quick reply. Gonna check if it works as suggested.

EDIT - After checking it gives me an error saying "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Comment: Nope. My mistake. It now runs but it still doesn't accept credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The results back will be in the dr variable and will depend on what the columns are in the table. Instead of * you should probably list the table columns that you want i.e.  User,password.  Then you can use the dr variable to get these values with statements like dr.getString(0) to get user and dr.getString(1) for password.   The variables user and password will not get changed by the query in your code. Also the literal strings "@user" and "@password" won't come out of the query so I don't know why you would compare to them. Instead you want to do something like. If (dr.getString(0)==user)

Please please encrypt the password in the database. You can encrypt what the user types and compare encrypted password to encrypted password.

Good luck

Comment: I think you mean something closer to this:

It still gives me an error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: `code`cn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from BDPerfil left join BDPerfilTecnico on BDPerfil.USER = BDPerfilTecnico.USER where BDPerfil.USER = @USER;", cn);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select NIF,PASSWORD from BDPerfil", cn);
            dr.GetString(0);
            dr.GetString(1);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    if (dr.GetString(0) == user && dr.GetString(1) == pass)
                   return true;